# How to get camera width and button width in NGUI

Tags: unity-game-engine, ngui

I am try to access width and height of NGUI 2D UI camera and also try to access width and height of button create with NGUI.

Comment: What version of NGUI?

Comment: i am using NGUI v3.5.4r2 version.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just figure out

```
UIPanel uiPanel = GameObject.Find ("UI Root").GetComponent<UIPanel>();

print(uiPanel.width");
print("uiPanel.height");
```

Answer (score 0):

Another method could be:

```
var uiPanel = NGUITools.GetRoot(gameObject).GetComponent<UIPanel>();
print(uiPanel.width");
print("uiPanel.height");
```

And you avoid looking for the object through all the scene hierarchy until find it. Also, if you are using multiple UICameras and therefore multiple UIRoots you make sure to get the correct one.